ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama'
I'm trying to execute the following piece of code:
import itertools
import jsonlines

from datasets import load_dataset
from pprint import pprint

from llama import BasicModelRunner
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer

The following error is appearing:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jigarpatel/LLMs/Course/FineTuningLLM101/FineTuningLLM101/.venv/bin/instruction_tuning_lab_student.py", line 7, in <module>
    from llama import BasicModelRunner
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama'

I am running code at PyCharm Community Edition on localhost.

try this:
pip install lamini

then:
from llama import BasicModelRunner


You can try doing
pip install llama-toolchain

